# How to handle banner ads on iPhone X in landscape

Tags: swift, admob, iphone-x, banner-ads

Has anyone got experience yet using banner ads, e.g from AdMob, on iPhoneX. I understand that we need to use the new safe area which seems fine in portrait mode but causes issues in landscape mode.

If we use the new safeArea insets the banner is floating above the new home button replacement swipe area. This is fine in Portrait mode but in landscape this is not ideal as it covers ever more screen estate and might block UI that previously was not be covered by the banner.

For example all my games are in landscape and the player tends to be right above the banner. But on iPhone X that banner in landscape is positioned about 20p higher thus now covers my player. It would not matter if the game was in portrait as we have extra screen estate at the top and bottom on iPhone X, kind of like a dead zone. In landscape however we do not have that extra screen estate at the top and bottom therefore having the banner sit above the safe area is not ideal as it’s covering more space now.

Can we use banners on iPhone X in landscape that are all the way at the bottom? Since games in landscape already cover all of the screen I presume the banner can be placed right at the bottom, below the safe area.

Comment: My quick check says the iPhone X "safe view" in landscape is 354 points in height, compared to an iPhone 8 that is 375. Between (a) properly used auto layout and (b) trying to gain 21 points of height... I have to ask *why*? I'd say if at all possible, fix the layout.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. What do you mean by fix layout? At the moment the banners are attached to the bottom/top superview. On iPhoneX  that means the banner will be all the way at the bottom covering the new swipe home button replacement area. If I use the new iOS 11 safe area for the banner constraints the banner will be above the swipe area. This is fine in portrait mode but not so much in landscape as we have a lot less space, height wise, thus the banner might cover UI that it should not. I am basically wondering if we have to use safe area when in landscape.

Comment: You probably should use the safe area. In your question you expressed a concern that the banner could potentially cover up some of your *app* layout - that's what I'd shoot to fix. If you are using auto layout everything should be pretty straightforward, even in landscape. And if you find yourself overly concerned with 21 points of height? Well, for me that's a screen layout to be refactored. (BTW, you don't *have* to do anything, including using the "safe area". But once you consider your customers, you probably should consider it.) Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for your detailed reply. My concern for banners  in landscape is mainly for games. I cannot just redo the UI as it would be a lot of work. Those 21 pixels really mess up my game as the character sits right above the banner basically. Now on iPhone x the banner covers the player by an extra 21 pixels. I am looking at the AdMob guide and they say safe area all the way. This will break a lot of games I think.

Comment: Final comments. (1) I don't use SpriteKit - I know some though - and I believe auto layout doesn't apply. (2) I'd *hope* that anyone with a game making $$$ in the AppStore has already considered things introduced in June - WWDC - and September - iPhone X. (3) I see what you are concerned about. Vertical size in your scenario may be an issue. You don't have the flexibility that `UIKit` apps might yield... table views, stack views, etc. That's a definite issue. (4) If totally stuck, consider... *why* is AdMob wanting the safe area? Maybe only for future devices? If so, go with the full screen.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for your help. I will probably make the banners not use the safe area in landscape and see what happens. If not than I will just stick with full screen ads as you suggested on iPhone X. Thanks again, really appreciate it.